# Issue in git between Heroku and Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I made an app, while working I stopped pushing code to heroku and only pushing it to bitbucket. When I tried to push it to heroku it wasn't accepting so I clone my heroku last directory and copy pasted files from bit bucket to directory to heroku clone directory.After This I was working on that directory only now I am not able to push to bitbucket is there any way I can do that. I am new to git.  .

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: when i was pushing code to bitbucket from heroku directory this:fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Try `git remote -v`. That should list your current remote repos. Take the value for origin and see if you can do a `git clone <origin value>` in a new spot. I would expect that to fail.

Comment: git remote -v is giving this: heroku git@heroku.com:niveshi.git (fetch)
heroku git@heroku.com:niveshi.git (push), i am able to clone from heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"origin" is not one of your defined remotes for some reason. To add it try the following:

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:<repo name>
```

You probably then want to set master to track origin/master:

```
git branch -u origin/master master
```

Comment: I did first command you mentioned and after this i try to push code. Got this error :Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.